# classify stable and unstable equilibrium points for differential equation $\frac{dx}{dt} = x(\lambda -x)(\lambda + x)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

I am doing exercise to find equilibrium points and classify them as stable/unstable for the following differential equation:

$\frac{dx}{dt} = x(\lambda -x)(\lambda + x)$

With $\frac{dx}{dt} = 0$, I can find the equilibrium points $x = 0, x = \lambda, x = -\lambda$.

However, I have no idea how to infer the sign of $\frac{dx}{dt}\Bigr|_{x=0}, \frac{dx}{dt}\Bigr|_{x=\lambda}, \frac{dx}{dt}\Bigr|_{x=-\lambda}$ in order to classify them as stable or unstable.

Could you please provide some directions so that I can continue to work on it?

Comment: Is $\lambda \neq 0$? Say, positive for example...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is easy to see that the equilibria of

$\dot x = x(\lambda - x)(\lambda + x) \tag 1$

occur at

$x = -\lambda, 0, \lambda, \tag 2$

since these are the zeroes of the cubic polynomial

$x(\lambda - x)(\lambda + x) = x(\lambda^2 - x ^2) = \lambda^2x - x^3.  \tag 3$

Note that we cannot "infer the sign" of $\dot x$ at any of these three $x$-values, since $\dot x =0$ has no sign; we can, however, find the sign of $d\dot x /dx$ at each of the critical values $0, \pm \lambda$.  Indeed, (3) yields

$\dfrac{d\dot x}{dx}(x) = \lambda^2 - 3x^2; \tag 4$

we see that, for $\lambda \ne 0$,

$\dfrac{d\dot x}{dx}(\pm \lambda) = -2\lambda^2 < 0, \tag 5$

but

$\dfrac{d\dot x}{dx}(0) = \lambda^2 > 0; \tag 6$

thus $x = \pm \lambda$ are *stable*, *attractors*, and $x = 0$ is an *unstable* zero, a *repellor*.

In the event that $\lambda = 0$, (1) reduces to

$\dot x = -x^3, \tag 7$

and (4) becomes

$\dfrac{d\dot x}{dx}(x) = -3x^2; \tag 8$

the equation now has one critical point at $0$, where

$\dfrac{d\dot x}{dx}(0) = 0; \tag 9$

the stability thus cannot be decided *via* the derivative of $\dot x$; we can nevertheless infer that $0$ is stable since $\dot x > 0$ to its left, and $\dot x < 0$ to its right, so points on either side flow towards $0$ under the action of $\dot x$.

Comment: The conclusion you have is backwards because of a sign error in equation $(3)$ of your work, which propagates.

Comment: @NinadMunshi:  you're right.  Just noticed that myself.  Under repairs.  ***Cheers!***

Comment: @NinadMunshi:  there, think I gots it patched up now!

Answer (score 2):

Assume $\lambda >0$.
Solving $x(\lambda - x)(\lambda + x)\geq 0$ you get $x\leq -\lambda$ or $0\leq x \leq \lambda$. Therefore $\pm \lambda$ are stable, while $0$ is unstable.
For $\lambda <0$ things are more or less the same.

On the other hand, if $\lambda =0$, the unique stationary point $0$ is stable.